# How RecyclerView's item interact to each other

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my recyclerView contain few option with checkbox. I need those options be able to communicate to each other, how should I do it?

I guess the functions should written in onBindViewHolder() but I'm not sure how to do it. 
I search through internet but I couldn't find a similar way to solve my problem.

For example:

```
-------------------------
1. All (With Checkbox)
-------------------------
2. Banana (With Checkbox)
-------------------------
3. Apple (With Checkbox)
-------------------------
4. Meat (With Checkbox)
-------------------------
5. Coconut (With Checkbox)
-------------------------
```

So when I check on "All" option, the rest of the checkbox must be check automatically by using onCheckedChangeListener().

The major problem I faced is, I have no idea on how item affect another item within Recyclerview.

Comment: can you paste your "OnBindViewHolder" code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what you wanna be ? 
[image]

In my opinion:
 First, we need add a property for Fruit to use CheckBox, ex: isFresh,...
 Second, change dataList (pass to RecyclerView Adapter) when tick CheckBox.
 Third, use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update RecyclerView UI.

Follow my github to get detail : https://github.com/pvnhat/ArchitectureComponentDemo/pull/2

Comment: I don't really understand Kotlin and need some time to digest your code. But yeah, probably this is what I want, will mark this as correct after I study through it. Thanks

Comment: Yep, Updating Data and notifyDataSetChanged() are the keys

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this

Ex. You can add isChecked property to your model

```
public class Fruit {
  private Boolean isChecked;
}
```

Then set it to true/false in OnClickListener of each item. You check it value in OnBindViewHolder to show UI checkbox ticked / not ticked

For Select All option, you can set

```
isChecked = true
```

for all items in list.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but how item affect another item within recyclerview? For example, by using setOnCheckedChangeListener(), if I checked on 1st item's checkbox, 2nd item's checkbox will be also check at the same time.

Comment: Which view are you apply setOnCheckedChangeListener() ? It will be easier if you can show your code